# Prevent browser from caching link destination

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.MVC application. There are some sites in the application which are accesible only with certain user permissions. If user doesn't have required permissions I am redirecting to another controller and displaying page with Not authorized message.

When user without permission tries to visit restricted page using a link, browser caches destination. So always after clicking this link user will be redirected to Not Authorized page, even if permissions are granted. Browser skips directly to cached destination.

I have disabled caching on server side but, this doesn't seem to work in this case, any ideas how I can prevent browser from remembering links destination?

Thanks in advance,
Konrad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no logical reason for such a behavior to occur. First, check to make sure that the user is authorized like you think they are and that your redirect code is functioning properly (such that it only redirects if indeed the user is unauthorized). Short of that, make sure you're using a temporary redirect, and not redirect permanent. Although the browser shouldn't decide to just cache the resulting page indefinitely either way, it would perhaps have more cause to think it *could* if you're sending a permanent redirect.

Comment: I am using filter to check if user is authorized and if he has permissions, but this works fine.
Could you write something more about temporary redirect? How I can make my redirects temporary, now I am using standard ActionLink helper

Comment: "now I am using standard ActionLink helper" - Not sure what you mean by that. The filter should be returning an `ActionResult` instance, which for a redirect, means using something like `Redirect`, `RedirectToAction`, etc. There's also "Permanent" versions of these: `RedirectPermanent`, `RedirectToActionPermanent`, etc. Make sure you're using the former rather than the latter.

Comment: ActionLinks are rendered as normal html links <a href="..." etc. 
filter is only redirecting using filterContext.Result = "notauthorizedurl" and only in case whe user don't have permissions required

So I don't think that I am using PermanentRedirect anywhere

Comment: I found out that there was permanent redirect call hidden deep inside our custom RedirectResult class. So thanks a lot for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I'm not entirely sure there isn't something else going on, but here's a thought:

You can programmatically construct a hyperlink in your razor page to build a unique URL each time the page is refreshed.  Just tack on a ?token=@uniqueVar onto the end of the url.  The token need not be used in any place in your code, but if your uniqueVar is a timestamp or a Guid or something, your URL will be different every time.

Comment: This is kind of solution but I have many links to restricted places, and don't want to do this kind of operation for all of them in application. More general solution would be more suitable